# FileNotFound exception when trying to move a file with File.Move

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013

I have a folder with over 2000+ MS Excel 2010 .XLSX spreadsheets and I need to perform the following actions:

- I need to open each individual file
- Copy the content of cell B4 (+ each file has unique content on cell B4), and
- append the content of cell B4 to the original file name

How can I fix this error so I can successfully rename my spreadsheets as mentioned above?

```
//file rename code
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Torename\");
FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f.FullName);
    Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;


    //Read the first cell
    string test = excelSheet.Cells[4, 2].Value.ToString();


    File.Move(f.Name, new_filename);

    ***Thank you for your assistance that did the trick
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.Move(f.FullName, new_filename);`

You have to use `FullName`, you need the full path.

**Edit:** Not part of your Question, but:

I'm not sure how `Workbooks.Open` works, but if you run into errors you might close the file before renaming it.

Also Adams comment.

Comment: @vba4all Also, does you cell contain the extension? Your path building is not including the original file extension in the name (but that might not be important to you and isn't anything to do with the bug).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thanks for input but this wasn't my question hehe I was just trying to help :) Please re-aim your comment at the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Close the workbook before moving it. Make sure to release all the resources associated with that file. 
And make sure you use the whole path in the names